# AAD B2C adding / mapping claims from external / delegate Identity Provider?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Using AAD B2C, I'd like to enable end-users to login using their Microsoft-Live or Google identity providers (delegate the authentication). However, I have a set of custom claims in AAD B2C for my users (some roles, for example). So, once the user authenticates into google, I need to add or "map, merge" the claim set with this user's custom claims in AAD B2C and return the consolidated claim-set to my application.

My question: where can I add or map these claims in the claimset returned by AAD B2C? In some Identity Providers this is possible using filters. Not yet finding the feature in AAD B2C, pointers?

EDIT: found this:
- https://aadguide.azurewebsites.net/claims/#claim-augmentation-/-enrichment

Comment: Hi @GGleGrand. By default, for each external identity, Azure AD B2C creates a user object in its own directory so that you can store claims that are asserted by the external IdP as well as claims that are asserted by the end user or your own application. If claims that are issued by the external IdPs don't map to the built-in or your custom attributes, then you might have to consider a custom policy for this. Does this help?

Comment: Thanks, clears up the general capabilities quite well.